# ngx Bootstrap Datepicker only to allow first day of a month

Tags: angular, datepicker

I want only the first day of each upcoming month to be selectable. All other days should be disabled.
So for example (today is the 01 Juli 2100), the next five valid dates should be:

1. 01.08.2100
2. 01.09.2100
3. 01.10.2100
4. 01.11.2100
5. 01.12.2100

Input Field in HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" bsDatepicker placement="top" [bsConfig]="bsDatepickerConfig" [minDate]="minDate">
```

bsConfig:

```
export const bsConfig = {
   dateInputFormat: 'DD.MM'YYYY',
   containerClass: 'theme-blue',
   showClearButton: true
}
```

minDate:

```
minDate = new Date();
```

What do I have to add to the bsConfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no exact solution of ngx bootstrap datepicker for my requirement, here's what I did.

A function which returns an Array with every first day of a month, two years from today.

```
function getDates(dateNumbers: number) {
  let dates: Date[] = [];
  let year: string = String(new Date().getFullYear());
  let month: string = String(new Date().getMonth() + 2);
  for (let i = 0; i < dateNumbers; i++) {
    if (month === '13') {
      year = String(Number(year) + 1);
      month = '01';
    }
    dates.push(utcZoned(new Date(`${year}-${month}-01`)));
    month = String(Number(month) + 1);
  }
  return dates;
}
```

In my component.ts I called the function and stored the dates in an array called enabledDates.

```
const enabledDates = this.getDates(24);
```

In my component.html I passed the enabledDates to [datesEnabled]

```
<input
   class="form-control"
   type="text"
   bsDatepicker
   placement="top"
   [bsConfig]="bsDatepickerConfig"
   [datesEnabled]="enabledDates"
   id="id_name"
   formControlName="fc_name"
 />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `datesEnabled` property. Create the `enabledDates` array dynamically for 1st date of each month

.TS

```
 enabledDates = [
    new Date('2020-02-06'),
    new Date('2020-02-08'),
    new Date('2020-02-11'),
 ];
```

.HTML

```
<input class="form-control" bsDatepicker [datesEnabled]="enabledDates" [bsConfig]="bsDatepickerConfig" >
```

Comment: What if I don't want to hard code the dates? Instead I want to enable every first day of a month.

Comment: I didn't find any such configuration in their documentation. You can check.